# OutOfMemoryError : no stack available

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I use an SQLite database to store data in my app. Here's a sample of how i access data on an asynctask :

```
ArrayList < Data > allMessages = new ArrayList<>();
String query = "SELECT * FROM ..........";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{username});
try {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Data data = new Data(c.getString(0),.....)
            allMessages.add(data);
        } while (c.moveToFirst());
    }
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

At runtime, i get this exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
```

At the moment, my database contains something like 20 records, which is - i believe - not enough to cause a memory overflow...

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `} while (c.moveToFirst());` that's an infinite loop. You are only reading the first record, forever

Comment: You mean `} while (c.moveToNext());`

Comment: Men i can't believe i didn't spot that ! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you only *ever* read the first record, because you use

```
} while (c.moveToFirst());
```

This will only ever read the first record, and your `ArrayList` will fill up with millions of copies of the first record.. And you will eventually get an `OutOfMemory` error.

---

Instead, use

```
} while (c.moveToNext());
```

Which will read all the records properly.